# rails connector for ckfinder or corefive.com/projects/filemanager

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor, ckfinder, file-manager

Is there any connector available for rails to use either ckfinder or corefive.com/projects/filemanager.

Or somebody guide me how to integrate any of these two with ckeditor in rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please visit galetahub's ckeditor for rails, https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

Comment: The link you point contain only the ckeditor integration and NOT the ckfinder.